# Can't calculate confidence intervals on a pooled dataset after MICE imputation

Tags: confidence-interval, r-mice

I preformed mice imputation on my dataset:

`LWP.imputeX<- mice(databasename, m=5, maxit=50, seed=500)`

Following this I ran a linear regression on the pooled dataset:

`PBMI_ModelX <- with(data=LWP.imputeX, exp = lm(SDS_BMI_y5_IOTF ~ Paternal_reported_bmi_BL)) summary(PBMI_ModelX) Pool_PBMI_ModelX<-pool(PBMI_ModelX) summary(Pool_PBMI_ModelX)`

Although I generated the summary statistics for this analysis when I try to get the 95% confidence intervals for the pooled dataset I receive the following error message -

`confint(Pool_PBMI_ModelX)`
Error in t.test.default(x, y = y, alternative = alternative, mu = mu,  :
not enough 'x' observations

I'm not sure why the confidence intervals won't work for me using the 'summary' or 'confint' commands as in my compete cases analysis I can generate them in this way.

Any assistance would be appreciated or if anyone could recommend any good references/sources for people from a non stats background on running MICE imputation. Thanks.

Comment: The `Pool_PBMI_ModelX` object has a different structure than what you get without imputation, i.e. from `lm(...)` alone. However, the summary does show an estimate and a standard error (which includes variance between imputations) for each regression coefficient, right? So you can calculate normal 95%CI for each coefficient like this: b +/- 1.96*se. If you provide the actual output of `summary(Pool_PBMI_ModelX)`, I can tell the code for this calculation.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I actually managed to get the 95% confidence intervals by adding 'conf.int = TRUE' beside the model summary. Code: 'summary(Pool_PBMI_modelX, conf.int = TRUE)